# The Ruby 'open class'-concept

Tags: ruby, class, object

I'm trying to create a number of objects from a class.

```
class Class
    def initialize (name=nil, age = nil, weight = nil)
        @name = name
        @age = age
        @weight = weight
    end
end
p1 = Class.new("Joe", 12, 135)
p2 = Class.new("Jack", 29, 200)
```

The problem is that the objects are not going to hold the same number of parameter. If I try to create a person that "does'nt have" a weight:

```
p3 = Class.new("Jill", 44)
```

This will affect the previously created objects, by removing their wheight as well, which is not what I intended to do. Is there a way to get around this, closing classes?
Or am I missing something vital?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My IRB session:

```
1.9.2p290 :001 > class MyClass
1.9.2p290 :002?>   def initialize(name = nil, age = nil, weight = nil)
1.9.2p290 :003?>     @name = name
1.9.2p290 :004?>     @age = age
1.9.2p290 :005?>     @weight = weight
1.9.2p290 :006?>     end
1.9.2p290 :007?>   end
 => nil 
1.9.2p290 :010 > p1 = MyClass.new("Joe", 12, 135)
 => #<MyClass:0x00000002226a08 @name="Joe", @age=12, @weight=135> 
1.9.2p290 :011 > p2 = MyClass.new("Jack", 29, 200)
 => #<MyClass:0x00000002212b98 @name="Jack", @age=29, @weight=200> 
1.9.2p290 :013 > p3 = MyClass.new("Jill", 44)
 => #<MyClass:0x000000021c9600 @name="Jill", @age=44, @weight=nil> 
1.9.2p290 :014 > ap p1
#<MyClass:0x02226a08
    @age = 12,
    @name = "Joe",
    @weight = 135
>
 => #<MyClass:0x00000002226a08 @name="Joe", @age=12, @weight=135> 
1.9.2p290 :015 > ap p2
#<MyClass:0x02212b98
    @age = 29,
    @name = "Jack",
    @weight = 200
>
 => #<MyClass:0x00000002212b98 @name="Jack", @age=29, @weight=200> 
1.9.2p290 :016 > ap p3
#<MyClass:0x021c9600
    @age = 44,
    @name = "Jill",
    @weight = nil
>
 => #<MyClass:0x000000021c9600 @name="Jill", @age=44, @weight=nil>
```

As you see there is no global override of `@weight`.

Comment: This is weird, it works fine for me aswell in this simplified version, but when i try to run it in my bigger program it seems to remove to prev. created objects' values. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Do not call your class 'Class';  each class is an instance of class Class.

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to redefine `Class`, you cannot do that. It already exists. The `Class` that you think you are defining is not your version. It is the already existing one. You can verify this by running `Class.superclass`, you'll see that it inherits from `Module`. Your version would not (classes that do not explicitly specify a superclass will default to inherit from `Object`)
You can however modify it using send, read more there => http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-send